# Как правильно написать, чтобы поля объекта были доступны только в классах наследниках, а в других классах только через getter?

Tags: java, ооп

Пишу игру на Java. Простой вопрос ООП (private, protected).
Есть два стула(класса)

```
public class Enemy{
    private int x;
    public Enemy(int x){
        this.x = x;
  }

  public int getX() {

        return x;
    }
}

public class Coin{
    private int x;
    public Coin(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
  public int getX() {

        return x;
    }
}
```

У них одинаковые поля. Я так понимаю, что надо создать общий класс GameObject, а потом унаследоваться от него
так :

```
public class Enemy extends GameObject{
    private int x;
 }
```

или так

```
public class Enemy extends GameObject{
    protected int x;
 }
```

Как правильно написать, чтобы поля GameObject  были  доступны только в классах наследнике Enemy, Coin  а в других классах только через getter.

Comment: что такое x ? координата стула по оси абсцисс?

Comment: Создаёте абстрактный класс GameObject с свойством protected int i. Не нужно переменную объявлять отдельно в классе наследнике.

Comment: Область видимости protected распространяется и на наследников, в отличии от private

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал @JavaJunior нужно создать абстрактный класс GameObject.

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    private int x;

    public GameObject(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX(){return x;};
    //когда класс будет расширяться, здесь появятся абстрактные методы
}

public class Enemy extends GameObject {
    public Enemy(int x) {
        super(x);
    }

} 

public class Coin extends GameObject {
    public Coin(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

И да, вам следует все-таки разобраться с модификаторами доступа